# Can I change Outlook Account settings without going through the Gui?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm trying to update the IMAP port for a mail account in Outlook 2016 and the GUI just hangs forever. I've reinstalled office with no luck and contacted Microsoft Support with no success yet.

Is there a way I can bypass this GUI process and just set the IMAP port manually? (by command line or by editing a file?)

(The updated IMAP port is correct and working with other mail clients)

Comment: Since you have the data files, have you tried to simply delete the Outlook profile, which results in you having to configure the account again of course.  I assume you believe the GUI hang is due to the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such an option to change IMAP port by command line or by editing a file.

How do you update the port setting? Via File > Account settings > Account settings?
In addition to a new profile mentioned above, we can also simply remove and re-add this account to Outlook client.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can go to control panel and search a Mail. In mail you can find the Email Accounts and can edit and add without opening outlook. Thanks